# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I need to navigate to m home screen when I press a button.
But I get an Error =>
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`

My Code

```
import React, { Component, useEffect  } from 'react'    
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements'         
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import screenStyles from './ScreenStyles';
import HomeHeader from '../components/HomeHeader';
import TicketCardList from '../components/TicketCardList';
import DisableModal from '../components/disableModal';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import {API_URL, API_TOKEN, API_URL2} from "@env"
import ClearLocalStorage from '../config/clearLocalStorage';

export default class CreateTroubleT extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    
    cancelButtonPress =() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeBottomBar');
        console.log("OK")
    }


    render() {

        return (                            
                            
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cancelJBDesing} onPress={()=> this.cancelButtonPress()}>
                        </TouchableOpacity>  
        )
    }
}
```

When I press the Cancel button I get the Error. I'm new to Native so  appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because when you pressed the button, you said you want to invoke `cancelButtonPress` with no parameter as shown below

```js
onPress={()=> this.cancelButtonPress()}
```

But when you defined `cancelButtonPress`, it is a function that expect a parameter as shown below

```js
cancelButtonPress (navigation) {
    navigation.navigate('HomeBottomBar')
    console.log("OK")
}
```

Since when you invoked `cancelButtonPress` without passing parameter, `navigation` is `undefined`, and which is why `navigation.navigate` throwing you that error.

**solution**:

Actually you should not be passing parameter when you pressed `cancelButtonPress`, because `navigation` is not something that you should pass via function call. Instead, you should update your `cancelButtonPress` function as below

```js
cancelButtonPress = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeBottomBar');
  console.log("ok");
}
```

Assuming that you've set up `react-navigation` correctly, it should be accessible via `this.props.navigation` instead

Comment: can you please let me know how to set up react-navigation

Comment: That is whole lot of works to do, if you tried my solution and it doesn't work, chances are your react-navigation is not being setup properly, and that definitely worth another question solely on it's own

Comment: @RyanFonseka: after updated your code what is the error you're facing?

Comment: console.log is working but not the this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeBottomBar');

Comment: @RyanFonseka: you mean you are getting `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')` similar error?

Comment: after your solution there are no errors but screen don't navigate

Comment: yup, which means like what I've said, you did not setup your `react-navigation` properly and that is a separate question on it's own. In that new question, what you can do is to share all the code you've setup related to `react-navigation` and hopefully someone will help you for that

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're not providing any argument to the function (hence the value of navigation is indeed `undefined`). Why don't provide an event `e` to the `cancelButtonPress` function an try to `console.log` the value of `navigation`?

You'll end up with something like:

`<TouchableOpacity style={styles.cancelJBDesing} onPress={e=> this.cancelButtonPress(e)}>`
(When it comes to your JSX).

```
cancelButtonPress (navigation) {
    console.log(navigation);
    navigation.navigate('HomeBottomBar');
    console.log("OK");
}
```

(When it comes to the function).

Such a thing will allow you to have a `navigation` object which value is different than `undefined`.

If the you don't want to over complicate yourself, you should just refactor your `cancelButtonPress`, in order for it to properly implement `navigation.navigate`.

You'll end up with something like this:

```
cancelButtonPress () {
   console.log("OK");
   this.props.navigation.navigate("/pathToHome");
}
```

In this case, you don't need to capture the `e` events as you don't really need to provide any arguments to your function to get the expected behaviour.

Comment: OP is working on a React Native project, so there is no `browserHistory` in the picture and `event` in the picture as it's not a web project

Comment: `onPress={e=> this.cancelButtonPress(e)}>` is wrong, there is no such `e` in `TouchableOpacity`